# Simultaneously display two independently loaded elements with different load times

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I am using jquery to load two different elements from separate sources into two different divs. This will replace content that is already in those specific divs. The first element being loaded is smaller, loads faster, and is displayed before the 2nd element is finished loading. Is there a way to 'load' that first element but not actually display it until the 2nd element has finished loading, so that both get displayed at the same time?

Here is my code:

```
$(this).attr('target','multiplayer_window');    
$('#gl_current_header').load(gl_data.site_url + parser.pathname + ' #gl_member_header > *');
$('#multiplayer_window').load(function(){
    //do some stuff;  
});
```

I am trying to get the #gl_current_header and #multiplayer_window to display simultaneously.

I've tried working with jquery's .promise(), .done() and experimenting with approximating load times with .delay(), but I haven't been able to come up with a working solution.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Very bad solution: a shared object (or just a boolean variable in this specific case, holding the slower responses status).

Comment: jQuery `.load` does not support promises. Use `$.ajax`, `$.when` and `$(…).html` manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using promises, you could hide them both initially, load the content into them and then when both contents are available, you show them:

```
$(this).attr('target','multiplayer_window');    
var def1 = $.Deferred();
$('#gl_current_header').hide().load(gl_data.site_url + parser.pathname + ' #gl_member_header > *', def1.resolve);
var def2 = $.Deferred();
$('#multiplayer_window').hide().load(function(){
    //do some stuff;  
    def2.resolve();
});
$.when(def1, def2).then(function() {
    // both are done here
    $('#gl_current_header, #multiplayer_window').show();
});
```

---

Here's an option that doesn't do any show/hiding (so no distracted movement of the page).  It loads the `#gl_current_header` content into an non-visible div and then when both it and the iframe is done, that content is transferred to the visible page element.

```
function replaceContent(url, selector1, selector2) {
    var def1 = $.Deferred(), def2 = $.Deferred();
    var container1 = $("<div>").load(url, def1.resolve);
    $(selector2).load(function() {
        // any other code here
        def2.resolve();
    });
    $.when(def1, def2).then(function() {
        // transfer newly loaded HTML to the page
        $(selector1).html(container1.html());
        // any other code here that runs when all new content is loaded and in the page
    });
}    

replaceContent(gl_data.site_url + parser.pathname + ' #gl_member_header > *', '#gl_current_header', '#multiplayer_window');
```

Comment: I ran into a couple of issues with this solution. The biggest being that #multiplayer_window would not show after it was hidden. I'm not certain why that's the case.   #multiplayer_window, however, being the slower of the two elements, didn't really need to be hidden anyway,so I removed the .hide(). The  second issue is again the .hide(). Because it is large, and already has content, #gl_current_user, looks very awkward when it just disappears while waiting for the other content to load.

Comment: @NathanielMiller - What is `#multiplayer_window` and what is the `.load()` operation doing on it?  I'd have to know that in order to know what else to suggest because to address the issues you're asking about, you can't use `.load()`, but will have to reimplement with finer grain control over when the content is inserted.

Comment: To answer your question, #multiplayer_window, is an iframe that has dynamic content being loaded into it. Essentially, content from the same page as what is in the iframe is being loaded into a separate div on the parent page. Depending on what content is loaded into #multiplayer_window, various classes are added or removed on the parent page. I have just been trying to keeping everything 'switching' at  simultaneously, instead of various items being loaded, elements changed etc. whenever they happen to be ready.

Comment: @NathanielMiller - Where's the code that starts the loading of new content into ` #multiplayer_window`?  That seems to be missing and is required for a complete solution.  It is possible to do this without hiding/showing elements causing things to go away/come back on the page if I can understand the whole context here.

Comment: The missing code is this simply 'if a specific link is clicked...' If it's clicked then the target becomes #multiplayer_window.

Comment: @NathanielMiller - but how does setting a `target` attribute on some other element cause an iframe to get new content loaded into it?  Sorry, but I know I can offer you an elegant solution if I understand enough about your code/HTML to do so and there isn't enough of a description disclosed yet.

Comment: OK, sorry for my lack of clarity :-/. What's happening is this. When an <a> is clicked I am parsing it and checking to see if it contains specific strings. for example.../messages/, a user name, etc. Depending on what that link is, it will get opened in a different frame, either the parent, or 1 of a couple of iframes. I can't hardcode the target to every <a>, so I'm using jquery to assign the various target attributes to the link, depending on what conditions are met.

Comment: In this case, when a link is opened in #multiplayer_window, a hidden element from that linked page is being loaded into a div, in the parent window.

Comment: @NathanielMiller - I added a new option to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like the same concept as my own submitted answer, but much more elegant :) I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url1Data = null;
var url2Data = null;

$.get("url1", function(data) { url1Data = data; if(url2Data != null) showData(); });

$.get("url2", function(data) { url2Data = data; if(url1Data != null) showData(); });

function showData()
{
   $('#gl_current_header').html(url1Data);
   $('#multiplayer_window').html(url2Data);
}
```

Comment: This solution looks somewhat promising, but I am uncertain how to implement it. My "url1" needs to include a specific id, as it's only a certain div i need from that URL. #multiplayer_window is actually an iframe, so I'm not sure about using .html() on it.

Comment: This solution doesn't only fetch the `#gl_member_header` subset of the load data like the OP's code does.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that seems to smoothly do what I need it to do.

I created an extra hidden div with a class of .holding-tank, and loaded the smaller, faster loading element into it. Then, when the slower loading element is finished loading, the .holding-tank is displayed with .show(), while the original div is hidden. The .holding-tank class is then removed and placed on the original div. That way the process can be repeated, alternating between whichever div is not currently being used.

```
$(this).attr('target','multiplayer_window');
        if ($('#gl_current_header').hasClass('holding-tank')){
            $('#gl_current_header').hide().load(gl_data.site_url + parser.pathname + ' #gl_member_header > *');
            $('#multiplayer_window').load(function(){
                $('#gl_current_header_alt').hide();
                $('#gl_current_header').show();
                // do other stuff
                $('#gl_current_header_alt').addClass('holding-tank');
                $('#gl_current_header').removeClass('holding-tank');
            });
        } else if ($('#gl_current_header_alt').hasClass('holding-tank')){
            $('#gl_current_header_alt').hide().load(gl_data.site_url + parser.pathname + ' #gl_member_header > *');
            $('#multiplayer_window').load(function(){
                $('#gl_current_header').hide();
                $('#gl_current_header_alt').show();
                //do other stuff 
                $('#gl_current_header').addClass('holding-tank');
                $('#gl_current_header_alt').removeClass('holding-tank');
            });    
        }
```